# Blackberry reading mod_deflate compressed page

Tags: apache, blackberry, mod-deflate

I am using Apache mod_deflate to return compressed html from a webpage.  It has reduced the generated page size from 3k down to 700 bytes.

How do I use HttpConnection in Blackberry to get the compressed page (i.e. only 700bytes instead of 3k)?

P.S.  Trying to use the GZIPInputStream(inputStream) keeps returning an incorrect header check error.

Comment: Asked another way:  Does anyone have any success in sending php:gzencode data to Blackberry/Java:GZIPInputStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you already tried to download and got non-compressed html page.

If so I think you should add "Accept-Encoding" header to your request ([question on forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/GZIP-Compression-Incorrect-header-check-with-MDS-Connection/td-p/1061867)). Try:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

Don't forget that you will get zipped data, so you need to unzip before using.

Also, as mentioned [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/4305/BlackBerry_Browser-4.6.0-US.pdf), gzip/deflate is not so efficient when your traffic is going over BIS-B, BES. Because BB servers will encode/decode data to analyze it and make it more efficient fro transmission.

Comment: Thanks.  I have added it.  Now I am getting "incorrect header check" from the line "data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(new GZIPInputStream(httpInputStream));"

Comment: Try using just gzip (deflate compression is not well defined).

Comment: I got it to work.  I am only using apache mod_deflate.  In PHP, I am only using "ob_start('ob_gzhandler');".  Working with gzencode required me to set a whole bunch of header values.  I was then able to read the stream on BB using byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(new GZIPInputStream(inputStream)), where inputStream = httpConnection.openInputStream();  BUT the setRequestProperty and getEncoding methods also did the trick.

Comment: I would recommend you to post your solution and accept as answer. So people will have more detailed answer in future.